# How can I count number clicks when countdown timer starts till it stops?

Tags: android, android-studio, countdowntimer

In my App when i click the textbox it starts counting number of clicks and when the textbox is clicked once the countdown timer starts .I want that my counter (mCount) stops when CountDown timer finishes up. Thanks in advance!!
Here is my code :

```
TextView tv,t1;

Button reset;

private int mCount = 0;

private final long startTime = 5 * 1000;

private final long interval = 1 * 1000;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private boolean timerStarted = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tv  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv.setText("5"); // startting from 5.
    reset=(Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);
    final TextView countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCount);
    t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
    t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!timerStarted) {
                countDownTimer.start();
                timerStarted = true;
                mCount++;
                countTextView.setText("SCORE: " + mCount);
            }
```

Comment: Mind explaining the issue you are having? hint: disable the TextView when the timer stops and enable it when it starts

Answer (score 0):

you can use the overriden method of countdowmtimer 
something like this:

new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

```
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
```

}.start();

Comment: but how does it help me to count number of clicks within the countdown Timer ?

Comment: onfinish() get called when your countdowntimer stops. so you can disable your textview

Comment: Can you please tell me how to implement onfinish() code ? I am new to Android .

Comment: onfinish is  overridden callback method which get call when countdowntimer stops. so you just have to put your code here what you want to do once timer stops.

Comment: public void onFinish() {
            MediaRouteButton textView2 = null;
            textView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            mTextField.setText("done!");

        }

Comment: when i put the above code , then it shows the app in unfortunately stopped when timer completed. what to do now ?

Comment: in the code first you assign textView2 = null and then try to assess it . so it will give null pointer expection...